# How to find max of specific rows and columns in a matrix in R?

Tags: r

I have been using apply(mydata,1,max); to get max of all rows. However, if my matrix has 6 rows, but I only want to find the max of the first 2 rows, how can I change this command to do just that?

Comment: Select the first two rows? `apply( mydata[1:2,], 1, max)`

Answer (score 0):

You can apply like

```
apply(mydata[1:range,],1,max)
```